# php serialize memory_limit issue

Tags: php

my script, serializing a large array was working without problems on PHP 5.3.8 with APC. My server crashed I installed PHP 5.3.10 with APC and I get following error.

```
Allowed memory size of 31457280 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262263 bytes).
```

I increased memory_limit to 256M in php.ini. On same script I verified with PhpInfo() and it is showing 256 MB. However I get the same error message. I disabled APC, and same error message again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, its pretty clear that 31457280 bytes is 30 MB, therefore the limit has not been increased, so i'd check that again.

To make this answer more useful, you should probably be looking at serialising this large array in batches, as its never a good idea to hog so much memory at one time.

Also, you should probably look into [igbinary](https://github.com/phadej/igbinary) since the native way PHP stores and serialises array is *very* poor and memory inneficient

Comment: I checked several times with phpinfo() and memory_limit is changed. serializing in batches is a good idea. igbinary is interesting, I will look at it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call phpinfo() to check if the memory_limit is actually changed. Maybe you simply edited the wrong php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

change in php.ini

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 300M
```

change memory_limit according to your needs.

or for detail, you goto http://php.net/memory-limit

Comment: how the script that you create. error was a sign that the process does not stop.